# Unable to login to wordpress interface

Tags: wordpress

I'm unable to login to wordpress admin page

Have enabled debugging, but I get the following error

```
WordPress database error: [INSERT, UPDATE command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table 'wp_options']
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_doing_cron', '1597323408.7079839706420898437500', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)
WordPress database error: [INSERT, UPDATE command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table 'wp_options']
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_timeout_block_lab_license', '1597409809', 'no') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)
```

Have restored from db backup and it works fine on another server, but not this one.  How can I resolve this?

Have also tried reparing the wp_options table.  problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the wordpress user needed

`GRANT UPDATE, SELECT ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';`
`GRANT INSERT, SELECT ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';`

Not sure why, this is global, but the user and db already existed on this server